# there is always an error...don't know why

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

i think my Insert into/ syntax is correct, but when i run the project there is always an error...
in this code i'm trying to add data to my database ms access 2013 using vb2012
here the code...

```
Private Sub btnadd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnadd.Click

    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
    dataFile = "C:\Users\hp-2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Delta\Delta.mdb"

    connString = provider & dataFile
    cnn.ConnectionString = connString
    cnn.Open()

    cmd.Connection = cnn
    addstring = "insert into Transaction (Customer_Name, Job, Trans_date, Amount ) values (" & C_name.Text & ",'" & C_job.Text.Length & "','" & t_date.Text & "','" & t_amount.Text & "');"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(addstring, cnn)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cnn.Close()
End Sub
```

this is the error...

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
```

Comment: Besides the obvious vulnerability to SQL Injection, you're not putting single quotes around the first value you're inserting.  Also, I believe (but am not certain) that `#` is used to delimit dates in Access, not `'`.

Comment: I've already put single qoutes but i have the same error ('" & C_name.Text & "')

Comment: I've tried other code

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182959/additional-information-invalid-cast-from-int32-to-datetime]

Comment: @Tim - can you please tell whats wrong..thNKs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if the problem were due to incorrect quoting in the `VALUES` clause, you would get a different error, either *"data type mismatch in criteria expression"*, or a message that the db engine expected a parameter value but you supplied none.

My guess is the syntax error is due to the fact that `Transaction` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#T).  See whether it works when you enclose the table name in square brackets.

```
insert into [Transaction] (Customer_Name, Job,  ...
```

If that change eliminates the error, I don't think you should stop there.  Switch to a parameter query, as others suggested, instead of building values into a string and executing the string.   In addition to protection against SQL injection errors, a parameter query would avoid complications with quotes in the `VALUES` clause.  And if you follow that advice, you should still bracket `[Transaction]`.  Better still, change the table name to a non-reserved word if possible.

Comment: ...didn't know that transaction is a reserved word..it works T.Y.

Comment: the code is working already..but the datagridview doesn't refresh when i add new data to the table..

Answer (score 0):

while it's essential to put single quote to the Name ('" & C_name.Text & "'), guess your amount is not a varchar column, so probably you could take the single quote away for that field.

the best way to debug this is watch the insert command (string value) generated and check whether there is any syntax error compared to your table design.

Comment: can you please...[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182959/additional-information-invalid-cast-from-int32-to-datetime]

Answer (score 0):

The customer_name is not in quote. You are also passing .Length, which I don't think it what you want to do.

Most importantly, you should put everything in parameters.

```
addstring = "insert into Transaction (Customer_Name, Job, Trans_date, Amount ) values (@Customer_Name, @Job, @Trans_date, @Amount);"

cmd = New OleDbCommand(addstring, cnn)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_Name", C_name.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job", C_job.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Trans_date", Convert.ToDateTime(t_date.Text))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", Convert.ToInt32(t_amount.Text))
```